# MIPS bgt instruction

Tags: mips

I am trying to create a simple program in MIPS, however I am already stuck in the beginning, I want the program to detect if the user enters a number bigger than 5000, but the program seems to just skip the " bgt " instruction! Also I'm unsure how to use "li" instruction those 2 problems might be connected!  Thanks in advance

```
 .data
 #Donnees textes
 lenombre: .space 32

 top: .word 5000
 msgerreur: .asciiz "\nLe nombre est invalide"
 msg: .asciiz "\nEntrer un nombre de 1 à 5000:"
 #segment de la mémoire contenant le code
.text
main:
  li $v0, 4
  la $a0, msg
syscall
  li $v0, 5
  sw $v0, lenombre
  j chiffre

#fonction chiffre
chiffre:
  li $t1, 4
  lw $t1, lenombre
  li $t2, 4
  lw $t2, top
  bgt $t1, $t2, erreur
  j main

erreur:
  li $v0, 4
  la $a0, msgerreur
  j main
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by removing "lenombre" variable and just storing the number input into $t0 register, it seems MIPS thinks "lenomre" is a string the way I defined it earlier, therefore comparing doesn't work